# Background music in storyboards

Tags: ios, xcode

How do i stop music when changing views in storyboards? Because storyboards dont have a viewwilldissappear option. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

But they do have **segues**.

Check out this tutorial: [storyboards and segues.](http://www.scott-sherwood.com/?p=219)

Answer (score 1):

`viewDidUnload`, `viewDidDisappear` depending on the circumstances, your question is pretty vague. Then all you have to do is call `[yourPlayer stop];` on `AVFoundation`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply so you think it will work if i do it in viewdidunload?

Comment: No, viewDidUnload is called to deallocate objects when memory is low, viewDidDisappear should to the trick.

Comment: I dont think i am going to have any luck on this, i even tryed to play the music with buttons and the stop button  is not working after changing views.thank you for taking the time to answer my questions!!

Answer (score 0):

Storyboard is just a way how you create your interface. It allows you to define the transitions between `UIViewControllers` and gives you an overral view of your application's workflow (although you should use other tools if you want to specify the workflow of your application). As for your questions, the `viewWillDisappear:` is called, I tested it now on an application using StoryBoards.